# How to list out all the EBS volumes in CLI

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

am using CLI to get the list of all EBS volumes with some specific tags.

When i use the specific tag am getting the output as none in my output...
I need to list out all the instance which is **Key:Environment Value: Prod**
I need the output in table format with the **headings**.....

**I don't know why am getting the none output in the column Environment**

As of now am using the query like:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filter Name=tag:Environment,Values=prod --query 'Volumes[*].Attachments[].{VolumeID:VolumeId,InstanceID:InstanceId,State:State,Environment:Environment}'
```

Am getting the output like:

```
DescribeVolumes                              |
+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------------------+
| Environment |      InstanceID       |   State   |        VolumeID         |
+-------------+-----------------------+-----------+-------------------------+
|  None       |  i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx |  attached |  vol-xxxxxxxxxx  |
```

Please help me

Comment: `Environment` is not a field on the `Attachments` object, hence it is returning `None`. You would need to navigate to the tags to include it, using something like `Tags.Values`. However, it would be a 1-to-many relationship, so this is unlikely to look good in such an output table. Have you considered writing the query in a language like Python instead?

Comment: @John  Rotenstein No...I didn't try code in python...could u please help me with my query..where should i add tags.values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When tinkering with parameters in the AWS CLI, I highly recommend reading:

- [JMESPath Tutorial](http://jmespath.org/tutorial.html)
- [JMESPath Specification](http://jmespath.org/specification.html#and-expressions)

Here's a version of your command that extracts the specific tag:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --filter Name=tag:Environment,Values=prod --query "Volumes[*].{VolumeID:Attachments[0].VolumeId,InstanceID:Attachments[0].InstanceId,State:Attachments[0].State,Environment:Tags[?Key=='Environment']|[0].Value}"
```

It basically says "Include the Value of the tag that has a Key of *Environment*".

You might need to play with the quote characters. This worked for me on a Mac, but Windows needs different quotes (eg single vs double).

Comment: Rotensten can u help me how can i get the instances in auto scaling group with the envionment and service tags...pls

Comment: Please create a new question with all the details.

Comment: I created the new question..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57158470/how-to-get-the-instances-in-the-autoscaling-group-with-specific-tags-using-cli...Pls help me

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --region=eu-west-2 --query "Volumes[*].{ID:VolumeId}" | grep ID | awk '{print $2}' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}'
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).