# How to get the instances in the Amazon EC2 autoscaling group with specific tags using AWS CLI?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, command-line-interface

I am trying to get all the Amazon EC2 instances with some specific tags like `environment` and `service` in **auto scaling group using the AWS CLI** .

As of now I included only one tag. How can I include both the tags and I need the full information of ID like Availability zone, launch configuration, instances, name, etc.

How can I do that?

I am using query like:

```
 aws autoscaling describe-auto-scaling-groups --query "AutoScalingGroups[? Tags[? (Key=='Environment') && Value=='staging']]".AutoScalingGroupName
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the information you seek (eg Launch Configuration) can be obtained from the Auto Scaling Group (using a command similar to what you provided above), while some of the information relates to the **instances that are launched within the auto scaling group** (eg Availability Zone).

Here is a command that will return information about instances in a specific Amazon EC2 auto scaling group (eg `my-autoscaling-group`):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filter Name=tag:aws:autoscaling:groupName,Values=my-autoscaling-group --query "Reservations[*].Instances[*].[InstanceId,Placement.AvailabilityZone,Tags[?Key=='Name']|[0].Value]"
```

Comment: i need to get for all instances...How can i do that

Comment: Your question says it is for all instances in an Auto Scaling group. What do you actually seek?

Comment: i need to list all the ASG instances with the tags environment and service

Comment: There is no such thing as "ASG instances". Rather, there are instances that have the `aws:autoscaling:groupName` tag set to the name of a particular Auto Scaling group. The above filter can be used to identify those instances. You can then add additional filters based on other tags.